# Multiplication of float with int in c

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    float var = 0.612;
    printf("%f\n",var);
    printf("%f\n",var*100);
    return 0;
}
```

o/p

```
0.612000
61.199997
```

I found that for JavaScript, we have `.tofixed()` method.

How do we get a fix for this in C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the precision when printing:

```
printf("%.3f\n", 100 * var);
```

Since the exact number you're having probably isn't representable in the `float` itself, there is no operation you can do on the number itself to "remove" the decimals, it's all a matter of how you choose to present the data.

Comment: Right, but probably the error shrinks if we replace `float` with `double`.

Comment: @phoenix as you shown in your output `.6f` shouldn't show ` 61.200000` thats the reason in answer `.3f`, decide your precision places, additionally consider glglgl's suggestion.